# Laravel 5.6 Route Model Binding with specific columns; How to keep Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing

I have set my route-model bindings in `boot()` function of `RouteServiceProvider` class as such:

```
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('itemById', function($id) {
      return \App\Item::where('id', $id)->first(['id', 'name']) ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

This returns an eloquent model object with the two columns I want, but none of the relationship methods of the model are returned. If I change the query part of the binding from `first(['id', 'name'])` to `first()` it works perfectly.

But I don't want to query all columns on the database for this item and I don't want to filter unwanted columns while returning a response to the webpage on the controller class. How can I make the binding return model relationships alongside desired columns? Thank you.

Comment: What is the data structure of your entry? And which database are you using?

Comment: If your relationships are belongTo, then you need to fetch the foreign keys along with id and name..

Comment: That fixed the `belongsTo` part but `hasOne` relationships are also affected. I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object`. This brings me back to square one and has practically no difference from fetching the item as a whole.